# Rails: organizing models in subfolders having warning: toplevel constant A referenced by B::A

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

Today I decided to reorganize big amount of user related models and I'm having a problem with it.

Before I had such structure:

```
app/models/user.rb
app/models/user_info.rb
app/models/user_file.rb
...
```

So I moved all `user_` models to user subfolder like this:

```
app/models/user.rb
app/models/user/info.rb
app/models/user/file.rb
...
```

and changed their definitions to

```
class User::Info < ActiveRecord::Base
class User::File < ActiveRecord::Base
...
```

`User` model wasn't changed (except associations).

Everything works fine except `User::File` model. When i'm trying to access this model i get the following error:

```
warning: toplevel constant File referenced by User::File
```

and indeed it returns standard ruby File class.

What i'm doing wrong?

UPD1:

```
root# rails c
Loading development environment (Rails 3.2.13)
2.0.0p195 :001 > User::File
(irb):1: warning: toplevel constant File referenced by User::File
 => File
2.0.0p195 :002 > User::Info
 => User::Info(...)
```

UPD2:

```
2.0.0p195 :001 > User::SomeModel
NameError: uninitialized constant User::SomeModel
2.0.0p195 :002 > User::IO
(irb):2: warning: toplevel constant IO referenced by User::IO
 => IO 
2.0.0p195 :003 > User::Kernel
(irb):3: warning: toplevel constant Kernel referenced by User::Kernel
 => Kernel
```

My app doesn't have any IO or Kernel classes, except ruby default.

UPD3:

```
# app/models/user.rb
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :files, class_name: 'User::File'
  ..
end

# app/models/user/file.rb
class User::File < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  # some validations, nothing serious
end
```

Comment: You need to provide more around the error message.

Comment: Have you tried with using a different name instead of File? Can you try Fil or something to check if this is not conflicting with existing Constants.

Comment: Where is the code that produces the error called from? From within the User class?

Comment: @sawa, there is nothing more to provide, see example in UPD1.

Comment: @Bala yes, i tried User::Fil works correctly. Also see UPD2

Comment: Can you show the code for the User::File class

Answer (score 29, accepted):

*Update*: This years Christmas present was the release of Ruby 2.5.0 with which this error won't happen anymore. With Ruby 2.5+ you will either get the constant you asked for or an error. For older Ruby versions read on:

Your `User::File` class is not loaded. You have to require it (e.g. in `user.rb`).

The following happens when ruby/rails sees `User::Info` and evaluates it (simplified; only `User` is defined yet).

- check if `User::Info` is defined - it is not (yet)
- check if `Info` is defined - it is not (yet)
- `uninitialized constant` -> do rails magic to find the `user/info.rb` file and require it
- return `User::Info`

Now lets do it again for `User::File`

- check if `User::File` is defined - it is not (yet)
- check if `File` is defined - it is (because ruby has a built in `File` class)!
- produce a warning, because we've been asked for `User::File` but got `::File`
- return `::File`

We observe that the rails magic, that automatically requires files for (yet) unknown constants, does not work for `User::File` because `File` is not unknown.

Comment: Thanks for explanation. Adding require at the top of `user.rb` gives me error - `.../app/models/user.rb:2:in `<top (required)>': User is not a class (TypeError)`, but adding require at the end of file solves the problem.

Comment: Beautiful explanation.

Comment: If I require `user/file` from `User`, I get a circular dependency error because `User::File` refers to `User`

Comment: I don't understand why `User::Info` should check that `Info` is defined. Returning `::File` instead of `User::File` seems wrong. I'd rather have an exception. It leads to weird behaviour : `My::Deeply::Nested::Dog` returns `Dog` the first time, and `NameError: uninitialized constant My::Deeply::Nested::Dog` the second time. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40928631/name-clash-with-top-level-constant-when-autoloading-with-rails/40930587?noredirect=1#comment69077891_40930587

Answer (score -1):

Try referring to the class as User::File to distinguish it from regular ruby Files. You can use ::File to refer to those when it is ambiguous